# Xubuntu 16.04 DVD playback jumps around in VLC and Parole

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, vlc

I couldn't get DVDs to play at all in VLC or Parole in Xubuntu 16.04 so I loaded a few packages:

```
sudo apt -y install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4
```

I was then able play DVDs. Sort of.

Parole still has a problem, but VLC can play it if I choose "No disc menu" when opening the DVD. For the test I used Avengers.

When the DVD plays in VLC, I get to the scene where Loki arrives. After a minute or two of this scene, it plays the same scene again. Then it jumps to Hawkeye getting hypnotized by Loki's staff. Then it goes to audio only.

VLC then becomes unresponsive and I end up having to Ctrl+Alt+Backspace to get out.

I also ran:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

As well as deleted the entry in ~/.dvdss - still no go.

I'm a bit surprised to see DVDs having a problem playing in a modern OS.

What gives?

Comment: Probably using some form of structure protection that may include bogus vts's, some of which don't allow real path. If possible play the disk in a hardware dvd player or maybe in Windows to find the real title number of main movie. Then `vlc dvdsimple:///dev/sr0@XX` where XX is the title number. Ex. - `vlc dvdsimple:///dev/sr0@18` plays title 18 on device sr0. (sometimes it may be a device of sr1). One could also add the starting chapter #, shouldn't matter.., ex. `vlc dvdsimple:///dev/sr0@18:1`

Comment: For avengers (not avengers2) I see some suggestion that it may be either title 28 or 35

Comment: I tried that method and it didn't work. Got errors: Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/sr0@28". Also, when I convert to MP4 in Handbrake off of the DVD, it's fine. Seems like Handbrake knows the order the pieces should be played in but VLC nor Parole do not.

Answer (score 0):

After loading and reloading libraries and many apps, I'm concluding that standard apps just won't play Avengers properly.
However, I loaded Kodi and it works! A little overkill for just playing a DVD, but hey, it works.